# How many weeks are there in a One Piece year?

Tags: one-piece

During the time-skip Luffy was sent to Rusukaina to train with Rayleigh. When they arrive Rayleigh introduces the island as follows.

> Rusukaina is home to the "48 seasons", a brutal island where the climate changes once a week.

This quote makes me wonder about the number of weeks in a year in One Piece. One would expect there to be 52 weeks as there are in our human world. So what about in the One Piece world? Are there 48 weeks in a year, 52 weeks in a year, or maybe a different number?

[image]

Comment: that sounds like it is 48 but may not be, we also divide year by (mostly) 4 season and have 52 weeks but every month have 4 weeks and remaining days which when add all it will be 52, so to confirm it, we should know how time is calculated in one piece universe, how many days 1 week have and so on, it is interesting question

Comment: I believe it was mentioned somewhere that the Grand Line time flow was convoluted, wish I remembered where exactly.

Comment: It sounds a hell of a lot better than "The 52.17857142-repeating seasons, or sometimes more on leap years".

Comment: @personabove they could have said 52 weeks instead of 48 obviously. The leap from 52.179 to 48 is not completely obvious to me.

Comment: I don't know but Oda as some sort of thing for punny numerology that i don't understand as I don't speak Japanese.  Also he probably has some idea what those seasons are.  If they are in a highly symmetric pattern, 48 has alot more factors to facilitate symmetry than 52.  That number probably came from one of those. It is unclear if it spreads to the whole world.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go out on a limb, and suggest that "once a week" is not precise. Most people would find it more convenient than "once every 7.6 days" or worse "every 1.1 weeks".

While it would be interesting to have complicated shenanigans, and I have no definitive proof that there aren't any, I think it's more just quick communication.

Comment: That would make sense if it would indeed be every 7.6 days (was this mentioned somewhere?) But Oda could have given it as many seasons as he wanted. So why did he choose for 48 specifically (or one season per 7.6 days as you said) and not 52 as I would have expected.